# Has everybody gotten their homework back?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-meaning

I am a TA (teacher assistant) at a university and want to make sure I have distributed all the graded homework to my students so I said

**Has everybody gotten their homework back?**

Is this a right sentence? if it is not what is the right one usually native speakers say?

Also, what verb I should use instead of distribute?

Comment: There are probably more idiomatic phrasings, but what makes you think that the above is wrong?

Comment: You can use “hand/pass back” instead of *distribute* and you can ask, “Did I miss anyone?”

Comment: @Jim: No thatnks.

Comment: @Hot Licks: I was not sure. Thank you.

Comment: @Saeed - No problem.  These are things I would say in that situation, but you are certainly free to say whatever you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Gotten" is a perfectly normal and neutral way of expressing this. There is no stigma or negative connotation here. Perhaps in a more formal or high-stakes situation you might want to be more precise, but "gotten" is perfectly acceptable.

For "distributed" in this case I would say "given back", since that's what you're doing in this case. If you were distributing cookies to everyone in the class, "distribute" in this case would mean "give away" or "give to", since that's what you're doing.

"Has everyone gotten a cookie?" would also work.

Note that "gotten" is not used in British English, and doesn't even seem to exist there. It's "got" in all cases, which I as a speaker of American English find imprecise and jarring.